# Image of critical points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$, $f:K^n\rightarrow K^n$ be an algebraic function, that is, $n$ polynomial functions in $n$ variables. Let $S$ be the set of critical points of $f$. If $K=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, then by Sard Theorem $f(S)$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ and, even, has Hausdorff dimension $\leq n-1$. There are $C^{\infty}$ functions s.t. the set of their critical values is dense but these are not polynomial functions (to my knowledge).

My question is: in the general case, does there exist a set $F$ s.t. $f(S)\subset F$ and $K^n\setminus F$ is a Zariski open set ? At least, is it generically true, that is to say, is it true if  the non-zero coefficients of the polynomials that define $f$ go through a certain Zariski open set ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My advice would be to consider the Jacobian of $f$. A point in $K^n$ is critical if and only if the Jacobian of $f$ at the point is not an invertible linear map (ie. its determinant is zero). So, $S$ is the locus of points at which the determinant of the Jacobian is zero. This should be a Zariski-closed subset of $K^n$. However, $f(S)$ need not be Zariski-closed in $K^n$. You might then set $F:=\overline{f(S)}$. This will work provided that $F\neq K^n$.

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, then the answer is yes, by the theorem called, variously, "Bertini's theorem" or "generic smoothness". See Shafarevich, Basic Algebraic Geometry 1, section 1.6 (IIRC).

Comment: @ Artie Prendergast-Smith , OK Artie, it is the second Bertini's theorem in Section 6.2 of Shafarevich's book. Such a closed set $F$ exists under the condition that $Im(f)$ is dense. Thanks.